# Large npm-cache folder on Azure DevOps private build agents

Tags: npm, azure-devops

The npm cache folders on our private windows Azure DevOps build agents become quite large.

C:\Users<srviceAccount>\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache
C:\Windows\ServiceProfiles\NetworkService\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache

I would like to run a clean task as part of our pipelines, but I'm concerned that this might cause issues for concurrent builds.  Is there a safe way of managing these folders?

Comment: If you want to clear old cache files, you could create a powershell script to prune files older than a date on this specific npm-cache folder.

Comment: I did consider that, but im not sure on the impact of the npm builds.  Will it just download them again if it needs them? if so am I better off removing the folder contents out of hours and letting the first build repopulate them?